# What does `{...}` mean in a python 2 dictionary value printed?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, ellipsis

While debugging a python program I had to print the value of a huge dictionary on a log file. I copy-pasted the value and when I assigned it in the python 2 interpreter I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. What? How was that possible? After a closer look I realised the dictionary in the file was something like this:

`{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': {...}}`

The key `three` value was `{...}`, which caused the invalid syntax error.

Pasting this dictionary on a python 2 interpreter raises a `Syntax Error` exception. Pasting it on a python 3 interpreter the assigned value results to be `{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': {Ellipsis}}`.

So, what does `{...}` mean in python 2 and why the syntax is invalid in python 2 even if the value is printed in the log file from a python 2 script?

Comment: Perhaps the logger abbreviated the output…!? It then becomes an invalid literal. `...` in Python 3 happens to be a valid literal, but obviously probably not the original value.

Comment: It looks like you put the dictionary inside itself as one of its own values.

Comment: as @deceze points out it is a standard way of leting you know that dictionaries can be nested, e.g. the value associated with a key can be another dictionary and so on (notation pbbly comes from infinite series as in 1+2+3 .....)

Comment: @khelwood yep, `d['three']` gives `d`. The dictionary was referencing itself. Thank you, the comments pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a dictionary like this:

```
d = dict(one=1, two=2)
d['three'] = d
print(d)
```

you get the output

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': {...}}
```

(though order may vary on older versions of Python).

`...` in container repr are used to indicate that a container contains itself, so that the repr doesn't become infinitely recursive.